# Parsing a JSON file in c# (Unity)

Tags: javascript, c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to parse a JSON file that I created from a JS app into Unity, in C#.

I have no experience with Json or reading data in general so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

Here is how the data structure looks like in JS:

```
function DialIn () {
    this.id = null; this.line = "default in line"; this.links = [];
}

function DialOut () {
    this.id = null; this.line = "defauLt out line"; this.links = []; this.autoDelete = false;
}

function DialNode () {
    this.id = null; this.posX = null; this.posY = null; this.ins = []; this.outs = [];
}
            
var NodesDB = []; //DataBase of dial nodes
```

In a nutshell, NodesDB is an array of DialNode and each DialNode contains an array of ins and an array of outs.

Once store in a JSON, it looks like something like this (for example, with 3 nodes in NodesDB)

```
[{"id":"dn0","posX":82,"posY":234,"ins":[{"id":"dn0_in_0","line":"This is dynamic Blep ?","links":[]}],"outs":[{"id":"dn0_out_0","line":"Coucou, this is a reply.","links":["dn1_in_0"],"autoDelete":false}]},{"id":"dn1","posX":520,"posY":171,"ins":[{"id":"dn1_in_0","line":"This is dynamic Blep ?","links":["dn0_out_0"]}],"outs":[{"id":"dn1_out_0","line":"Coucou, this is a reply.","links":[],"autoDelete":false},{"id":"dn1_out_1","line":"Coucou, this is a reply.","links":["dn2_in_0"],"autoDelete":false}]},{"id":"dn2","posX":948,"posY":139,"ins":[{"id":"dn2_in_0","line":"This is dynamic Blep ?","links":["dn1_out_1"]}],"outs":[{"id":"dn2_out_0","line":"Coucou, this is a reply.","links":[],"autoDelete":false}]}]
```

Then, in Unity, I created this structure, trying to mimic the structures from JS:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    class DialIn
    {
        string id; string line; string[] links;
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    class DialOut
    {
        string id; string line; string[] links; bool autoDelete;
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    class DialNode
    {
        string id; int posX, posY; DialIn[] ins; DialOut[] outs;
    }

    DialNode[] NodesDB;
```

From there, I'm using these commands:

```
path = Application.dataPath + "/Jsons/Bloup.json";
jsonData = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

And I believe I should use something like this:
`NodesDB = JsonUtility.FromJson<DialNode>(jsonData);`

But apparently, it's not that simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :o

Comment: I have created a much simpler version of my script without the arrays of arrays and all that noise. The FromJson is working well in that case.

I think the problem is that my Json doesn't contain a class but an array of said class. I haven't found a workaround,though. I'm looking into this: 
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1123326/jsonutility-array-not-supported.html

Answer (score 4):

Make all your object's member variables `public`. JSONUtility doesn't (de)serialize private member variables.
See the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html).

Alternatively if you really want your member variables private, add the `[SerializeField]` attribute to every field you want serialized.

Comment: I've made all of my classes and NodesDB public but there is still a few things wrong.

This is where I want to put my data:
``public DialNode[] NodesDB;``

But when I use the command
``NodesDB = JsonUtility.FromJson<DialNode>(nodesData);``
I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type DialNode to DialNode[]"
I don't see how to deal with the array, but I'm not even sure I get the syntax right, with the FromJson.

Comment: I can work around the error using ``NodesDB = JsonUtility.FromJson<DialNode[]>(nodesData);`` but then, I get:
"ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type."

Comment: I guess  you need another class to wrap around your nodes array, and your json should not start with an array as the root, but should look like this: `{ "nodesDB":[{...},{...},etc]}`. Does that help?

Comment: It does! I've been reading that Unity's parser is not supporting arrays at the root of the json file. I guess once the data is extracted, I can get rid of this 'container' and there we go =)

Answer (score 1):

you can add [**simple json**](https://github.com/HenrikPoulsen/SimpleJSON/blob/master/SimpleJSON.cs) to your project and them using on your top script,
I use this Script for parse and other...

```
 var N = JSON.Parse(the_JSON_string);
 var versionString = N[0]["id"].Value;  
 var versionString = N[0]["posX"].Value;
```

and other ....